# Collection view scroll with animation causing wrong image positions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to reload the data in the collection view, in order to set a new cells sizes according to the new data source .
Than i have to scroll to the start, and i would like to do that with animation . 
every row has 1 cell in it .

So, using this :

```
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    [self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

Whats happens is that it scrolls to the start, and reloaded, but when he comes to image 1 , than i see many images replaced fast, and it stopes on some image that is not belong to the first cell, but to other cell .

If i scroll to the start- **without** animation (a`nimated:NO`) its *not* happens .
I need that animation.
What could cause this problem ?

**EDIT:**
I can see a similar problem when i scroll fast ,i can see images that are changing very fast in their cells before they turned to the final image that should be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that cells are reused,

So let's see this example

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourCellId"];
    cell.image = nil;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        UIImage *image = [self imageForIndexPathRow:@(indexPath.row)];
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           cell.image = image;
       });
    });
    return cell;
}
```

As the operations are asynchronous, scrolling fast will cause to dispatch 2 operations for 1 cell.

For example lets name some cell pointer "ImageCell-1"
Now lets see, what will be, if you start fast scrolling, and 2 operations are dispatched.
First operation loads "a.png", and download is active, you scroll fast and "ImageCell-1" is now being loaded "b.png" (but "a.png" is still loading).

So "a.png" completes download and is set to "ImageCell-1", then completes "b.png" and is set to "ImageCell-1".
*(this is the issue that you see =>  "I can see a similar problem when i scroll fast ,i can see images that are changing very fast in their cells before they turned to the final image that should be loaded.")*

But also can be situation (when you use "high level libraries" like AFNetworking, when queues are managed by them, and  concurrency downloading is available) "b.png" completes download and sets it to "ImageCell-1", after that completes "a.png" download and set to "ImageCell-1". This will cause to see is "a.png" instead of "b.png".

The solution is to cancel download operation, before starting new one, if you are using AFNetworking, keep NSOperations, and call `[operation cancelOperation];` before starting new download.

**EDIT:**
If you're using NSURLConnection, you need to switch to modern way of using NSURLSession (to support request canceling).

Here I have wrote a small method, which resolves your problem

```
@interface MyCell ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask;

@end

- (void)loadImageFromPath:(NSString *)aPath
           availableCache:(NSCache *)aCache
{
    if (self.dataTask) {
        [self.dataTask cancel];
    }

    NSData *cache = [aCache objectForKey:aPath];
    if (cache) {
        self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:cache];
        return;
    }
    self.dataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aPath]
                                      completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                                          NSURLResponse *response,
                                                          NSError *error)
                                {
                                    if (data) {
                                        self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                                        self.dataTask = nil;

                                        // Add to cache
                                        [aCache setObject:data forKey:aPath];
                                    }
                                }];
    [self.dataTask resume];
}
```

Place this method in your Cell,

And call it from `cellForRow`, like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourCellId"];
    [cell loadImageFromPath:imagePath availableCache:self.cache];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks, you have explained the problem well, but the solution is not so clear. if you cancel one operation before starting a new one, you will have a serious problem with the regular loading. so when the program starts, it than tries to load cells 1 2 3 4 (Are visible) ,but when it starts 1 ,than comes 2 , it than cancels(1 ) ?? not clear to me . and by the way ,i dont use AFNetworking, i dont like it. i load images like the answer you gave me in the other question ..

Comment: and by the way , i think the problem can be described other than that. i dont think there are 2 operations for the same cell. I think that when i go up, so for example cell 6 is starts downloading image, when i go up to cell one, than cell6 becomes 1(reused) and i see in 1 the image from 6. if not using AFNetworking, how would you take care of that problem, ?

Comment: I think a better solution would be to load images only when the scroller is decelerating, than you have some kind of low pass filter on the data.

Comment: @Curnelious I'm about that problem => when i go up to cell one, than cell6 becomes 1(reused) and i see in 1 the image from 6. This is simply solved by canceling download operation for 6 and starting download for 1.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand what is going on here. if you cancel an operation while its being happens, you will lose many images, because the system say-ok now load cells 1 -2 -3 . than 1 starts, than comes 2, it stops 1 before it even finished, and starts 2, than right away comes 3, you stop 2 and start 3 , at the end, you will only have image 3 .  second thing is, where is the thread block ? you can't have NSData operation without async because it will affect the UI .

Comment: @Curnelious, "than 1 starts, than comes 2, it stops 1 before it even finished" - No :), I'm stoping 1 cell download when 6 is started. i.e. I'm stoping download of not visible cell.

Comment: When the program is start : in that second, the collection view tells the delegate to load 3 visible cells: 1 , 2  ,3 . if you load 1 than cancel it, you will not see it even if its a visible cell. What am i missing here? :)

Comment: you are based on the fact that an image is loaded fast enough before the next visible cell will appear? thats a problem. the first 3 delegates comes in about 500ms, to load the first 3 cells. so right when you start the first, you stop it before it even finished.

Answer (score 1):

I think i solve the problem, or improved things a lot .

Well when you start downloading from the net, give your block a tag :

```
- (void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url AndTag:(int)Gtag completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded, NSData *data,int tag))completionBlock
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    int thetag=Gtag;
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {

             completionBlock(YES, data,thetag);
         }
         else
         {

             completionBlock(NO, nil,thetag);
         }
     }];
}
```

Than, when the download complete, we will check if the cell is on screen right now , if its not, we will not load its image to the cell :

```
  [self downloadImageWithURL:url AndTag:(int)cell.tag  completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSData *data,int tag)
         {

     BOOL isvisible=0;
                 for (iPhoneCostumCell *tcell in [self.collectionView visibleCells])
                 {
                    if(tcell.tag==tag)
                    {
                        isvisible=1;
                        break;
                    }
                 }
```

I think this is a good solution , and it makes things more stable . It also makes the processor work less, because if we dont find the image, we dont continue to the NSData conversion-made in another thread .

Comment: this will resolve the issue, but the download operation will cause, other cell to load after some delay (not imediate)

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        [self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
    } completion:nil];
}];
```

Try to make your own animation.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a bad solution, not only that its not solving the problem,if you try this, you will see that you get a very unwanted behaviour of the scroll view. Please check my answer, i think it makes thing work better .

Comment: I did't knew what's happening in your code. Great to hear that you solve it.